# Trying to settup Django on Apache2: 'not able to import' django.core.wsgi

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, apache2, mod-wsgi

My Django set-up works locally, but when I try to run it with Apache2 on Ubuntu and go to the IP, it gives me a 500 internal error message Internal Server Error

> "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request."

Checking my error logs I see that there is a problem with 'django.core.wsgi'. The error message being:

> Traceback(most recent call last):, referer: http://*My-IP-Address*/
>   [Sun Jan 24 15:32:56.099311 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 9919:tid 139760998606592]
>
> [client 86.45.29.184:53665]   File
>   "/home/USER/my_django_project/my_django_project/wsgi.py", line 17, in
>   , referer: http://*My-IP-Address*/
>
> [Sun Jan 24 15:32:56.0993522016] [wsgi:error] [pid 9919:tid 139760998606592     >[client
>   86.45.29.184:53665]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application, referer: http://*My-IP-Address*/
>
> [Sun Jan 24 15:32:56.099364 2016] [wsgi:error] [pid 9919:tid 139760998606592]
>   [client 86.45.29.184:53665] ImportError: No module named
>   django.core.wsgi, referer: http://*My-IP-Address*/

My etc/apache2/sites-enabled
folder has my my_django_project.conf file, this is settup as:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/USER/my_django_project/my_django_project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /home/USER/my_django_project

<Directory /home/USER/my_django_project/my_django_project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Order deny,allow
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /media/ /home/USER/my_django_project/django_proj/media/
Alias /static/ /home/USER/my_django_project/django_proj/static/

<Directory /home/USER/my_django_project/django_proj/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/USER/my_django_project/django_proj/media>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My wsgi.py file looks like:

```
"""
WSGI config for my_django_project project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os, sys

sys.path.append('/home/USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')

sys.path.append('/home/USER/my_django_project/my_django_project')


from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_django_project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Thank you for reading
 :D

Comment: Do you have modwsgi installed for correct Python version (which is used by Apache)?

Comment: This is what I see when I restart the server.. : Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.10

Comment: Try appending your virtual environment to `WSGIPythonPath` in your Apache config, instead of appending it in your wsgi file, [as shown in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-a-virtualenv).

Comment: just tried that, still get " ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi" :( (for what it's worth, I'm NOT using a virtual environment)

Comment: Where is Django installed? You could check with `python -c 'import django; print(django.__file__)'`

Comment: It's here "/home/USER/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.pyc"  Thanks Alasdair for your help :) Much Appreciated